# D3 multi-series line chart from pivoted JSON

Tags: d3.js

There is a great example of a multi-series line chart here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 and if the tsv data were laid out I'm sure it would look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "date": "20111001",
    "New York": "63.4",
    "San Francisco": "62.7",
    "Austin": "72.2"
  },
  {
    "date": "20111002",
    "New York": "58.0",
    "San Francisco": "59.9",
    "Austin": "67.7"
  },
  {
    "date": "20111003",
    "New York": "53.3",
    "San Francisco": "59.1",
    "Austin": "69.4"
  }
]
```

The issue I have is that I may not always know the keys, cities in this case, and would not want a solution that stores the cities in the key.

If my data looked like this:

```
[
    {
        "City": "New York",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Date": "20111001",
                "Value": "63.4"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111002",
                "Value": "58.0"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111003",
                "Value": "53.3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "City": "San Francisco",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Date": "20111001",
                "Value": "62.7"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111002",
                "Value": "59.9"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111003",
                "Value": "59.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "City": "Austin",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Date": "20111001",
                "Value": "72.2"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111002",
                "Value": "67.7"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111003",
                "Value": "69.4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to map my data to the first format OR what would I need to change in the code to get the same multi-series line chart?

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p8S7p/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The date in the example, is actually transformed somewhat to look like the data you have:

```js
var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    values: data.map(function(d) {
      return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]};
    })
  };
});
```

The difference is that this data contains only arrays of arrays while your format contains array of objects, where each object contains the array inside the *object* as `obj.Data`.

It is easy to make the changes to make the demo run [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JYS8n/1/).

The primary problem was how to calculate the *min/max* of the `Date` and `Value` for the scales:

In the original example:

```js
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.date;
}));

y.domain([
d3.min(cities, function (c) {
    return d3.min(c.values, function (v) {
        return v.temperature;
    });
}),
d3.max(cities, function (c) {
    return d3.max(c.values, function (v) {
        return v.temperature;
    });
})]);
```

For the changed format:

```js
var minX = d3.min(data, function (kv) { return d3.min(kv.Data, function (d) { return d.Date; }) });
var maxX = d3.max(data, function (kv) { return d3.max(kv.Data, function (d) { return d.Date; }) });
var minY = d3.min(data, function (kv) { return d3.min(kv.Data, function (d) { return d.Value; }) });
var maxY = d3.max(data, function (kv) { return d3.max(kv.Data, function (d) { return d.Value; }) });

x.domain([minX, maxX]);
y.domain([minY, maxY]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My only question is what has happened to the x-axis path in the demo jsfiddle? It has gone wonky.

Comment: I had reduced the `width`. Restoring it removes the _wonkiness_: http://jsfiddle.net/JYS8n/2/

Comment: No, that isn't what I meant. The d3 line path for the x-axis is missing (or at least wonky).

Comment: The x-axis is not present in the original example either. The CSS `.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}` disables it.

Comment: No problem. Happens. :-)

Comment: How can I add only dates on x-Axis like, 2011/01/01 and not time and Days?

Comment: @KomalGupta You will need to use [`axis.tickFormat`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickFormat) and pass a [`d3.time.format`er](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/ca0adb7e426c12c06a95) to it.

Comment: @musically_ut: Thanks. I am using same logic to plot multi-line chart. But my lines are not drawing over entire svg but stays at top left corner of the chart. Could you please point where I might be going wrong?


[![multilinechart][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6df4.png

Comment: I have modified the "Value",it's not right.http://jsfiddle.net/6wauboxb/

Comment: @Shally12 I don't fully follow. I think it would be worth posting it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

One answer, if i want read this date of file/url with json equals, how i read this??

Solution:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
color.domain(data.map(function(key) {
return key.data;
}));
```

Comment: I find the solution, i post solution